# How do I understand $\Pi a_i=\cap a_i$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This is a dumb question but I hope anyone please help me understand this.

On Atiyah-Macdonald chapter 1, the statement says that $\Pi a_i=\cap a_j$
where $a_i$ and $a_i$ ($i\neq j$) are coprime ideals.

First, I don't understand how the direct product of the ideals can be written as being equal to an ideal. Even if it's an isomorphism, I don't think it makes sense.

In the proof, the author seems to use the fact that this direct product is the same as the product of the ideals, which confuses me because the direct product and product can never be isomorphic.($0\cdot 1\to 0, 0\cdot 2\to 0$).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. But what confuses me is that just before the statement Atiyah-Macdonald notate that $\Pi$ is the direct product

Comment: Might it have said $\bigcap a_j$ rather than $\cap a_j\text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Sorry,, what is the difference?

Comment: I had in mind only a typographical difference. $\qquad$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\prod \mathfrak a_i$ is not a direct product of ideals. It's just a product of ideals. The product $\prod \mathfrak a_i$ is a new ideal, generated by all the elements of the form $x_1x_2x_3\cdots$ where $x_i\in \mathfrak a_i$ (or, to copy Atiyah-MacDonald: $\prod x_i$). We of course need here that all the $\mathfrak a_i$ are ideals of a single ring.

Further up on page 7, yes, the authors talk about the *direct product of rings*, and notated it $\prod A_i$. This is not the same as the product of ideals $\prod \mathfrak a_i$. It is unfortunate that they look so much alike, but it is what it is.